# Restrict control in nav-menu for specific role

Tags: menus, user-roles

I'm trying to figure out how to control certain functions for non-admins within nav-menus.php.

Normally it is possible to add and/ or rename menu's. I don't want non-admins to be able to do this.

How can I remove (not hide with css) the function to create and rename menu's?

[image]

Comment: WordPress doesn't provide distinct capabilities for these functions. Complete control over menus is granted based on the `edit_theme_options` capability .

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is the harm in allowing the user to create more menus if the theme doesn't do anything with those menus? In theory, each menu should be only assignable to 1 `theme_location` ( based on `wp_nav_menu()` ).

Comment: This Wordpress is build for clients. I'm trying to build this as clean as possible, trying to prevent questions like: "i've added a menu but nothing is happening".